# How to load and merge multiple .csv files in r?

Tags: r, csv, merge

So I'm very new at R and right now I'm trying to load multiple .csv files (~60 or so) and then merge them together. They all have similar columns and their files are named like this: dem_file_30, dem_file_31.

I've been trying to use scripts online but keep getting some errors. I'm sure I can do it by hand but that would be really tedious.

Example:

```
file_list <- list.files("/home/sjclark/demographics/")   
list_of_files <- lapply(file_list, read.csv)  
m1 <- merge_all(list_of_files, all=TRUE)
Error: merge_all doesn't exist
```

This one seems to read them into R, but then I'm not how to do after that... help?

```
setwd("/home/sjclark/demographics/")
filenames <- list.files(full.names=TRUE)  
All <- lapply(filenames,function(i){
read.csv(i, header=TRUE)
})
```

Comment: merge_all is probably not a function from base R. Where is it from?

Comment: Is it from the reshape package? If so, please install and load the package.

Comment: as it's been pointed in the comments, maybe you don't want to _merge_ (which in R is the SQL-equivalent of _join_) but to _concatenate_ or _append_ the files, is this right? If so, please edit your question because it will be useful for many more generations to come :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears as if you might be trying to use the nice function shared on [R-bloggers (credit to Tony Cookson)](https://www.r-bloggers.com/merging-multiple-data-files-into-one-data-frame/):

```
multMerge = function(mypath){
  filenames = list.files(path = mypath, full.names = TRUE)
  datalist = lapply(filenames, 
                    function(x){read.csv(file = x,
                                         header = TRUE,
                                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)})
  Reduce(function(x,y) {merge(x, y, all = TRUE)}, datalist)
}
```

Or perhaps you have pieced things together from difference sources? In any event, `merge` is the crucial base R function that you were missing. `merge_all` doesn't exist in any package.

Since you're new to R (and maybe all programming) it's worth noting that you'll need to define this function before you use it. Once you've done that you can call it like any other function:

```
my_data <- multMerge("/home/sjclark/demographics/")
```

Comment: When I plug it in with "merge" instead of "merge all" I get this: Error in as.data.frame(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default

Comment: As the blog post explains, `merge` only operates on two objects at a time. The function I just shared takes care of this by using another function called `Reduce` to iteratively apply merge over your data list. I don't think there's a more parsimonious way to accomplish this task than with the function presented here.

Answer (score 4):

I have just been doing a very similar task and was also wondering if there is a faster/better way to do it using `dplyr` and `bind_rows`.

My code for this task is uses `ldply` from `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)    
filenames <- list.files(path = "mypath", pattern = "*", full.names=TRUE)
import.list <- ldply(filenames, read.csv)
```

Hope that helps

Rory

Comment: So OP needed to **append** not merge? Semantics is very important.

Comment: @JulietR if you are happy with this answer can you please accept it/up voted it please

Comment: Yes! upvoted it but since I'm so new to the site it might not publicly show up.